# Elasticsearch multi-select faceting

Tags: filter, elasticsearch, multi-select, faceted-search, facet

Lets imagine we have the following documents:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/multiselect/demo/1' -d '{
    "title": "One",
    "tags": ["tag1"],
    "keywords": ["keyword1"]
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/multiselect/demo/2' -d '{
    "title": "Two",
    "tags": ["tag2"],
    "keywords": ["keyword2"]
}'
```

If we do the query:

```
curl -XGET '
{
    "post_filter": {
        "and": [
            {
                "terms": {
                    "tags": [
                        "tag1",
                        "tag2"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "terms": {
                    "keywords": [
                        "keyword1"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "aggs": {
        "tagFacet": {
            "aggs": {
                "aggs": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "tags",
                        "size": 0
                    }
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "terms": {
                    "keywords": [
                        "keyword1"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "keywordFacet": {
            "aggs": {
                "aggs": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "keywords",
                        "size": 0
                    }
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "terms": {
                    "tags": [
                        "tag1",
                        "tag2"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

We will have a document "One" and a list of facets: tag1 - 1, keyword1 - 1, keyword2 - 0 and tag2 - 1, but actually the last one tag2 should not be there, because we don't have anything for the keyword2 in our filter (and the facets).

The question is, is there are any possibility to get facets without tag2, and not to make 2 requests.

Let me know, if you need a better explanation, but I guess the basic idea should be clear.

PS. Some better explanation of the following pattern you can find out here: https://gist.github.com/mattweber/1947215; it's the same thing, and it have the same issue described here.

[image]

Comment: Can't you use aggregation?

Comment: Actually I'm using aggregation, but it works identically!

Comment: Can you look again, if I get it correct?

Comment: Oh, I've forgot to include post_filter block :( sorry.

Comment: The idea is following, everything is works correctly, the only issue with UI. It's hard to explain the whole situation, and I made it few times already.